# Android Cloud Firestore add new Item to Sublist of Document

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

i need to add an Item to a list inside my Document. Unfortunately my code is always overwriting the old value. How can i change the code to add always the new item?

```
  db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    db.collection("Users").document(userid);

    Map<String, Object> docData = new HashMap<>();

    Map<String, Object> nestedData = new HashMap<>();
    nestedData.put("Ernährung2", true);


    docData.put("channelAbos", nestedData);
    db.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .set(docData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding `SetOptions merge()` method as the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/android/SetOptions.html#merge()) says:

> Changes the behavior of set() calls to only replace the values specified in its data argument. Fields omitted from the set() call will remain untouched.

So `SetOptions.merge()` method will only replace the fields under fieldPaths. Any field that is not specified in fieldPaths is ignored and remains untouched.

As a conslusion, if the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document does exist, its contents `will be overwritten` with the newly provided data, unless you specify that the data should be merged into the existing document. So, to solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
db.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
.set(docData);
```

to

```
db.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
.set(docData, SetOptions.merge());
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document), set() called with one argument overwrites the entire document every time.

> If the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document
>   does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided
>   data

If you want to add a value to an existing list, you should use FieldValue.arrayUnion() as described in the [same page of documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

> If your document contains an array field, you can use arrayUnion() and
>   arrayRemove() to add and remove elements. arrayUnion() adds elements
>   to an array but only elements not already present.

I will point out that what you're doing right now with a Map will create an object, not a list.  Please be certain that you have a list/array type field and not an object to work with.